# Texture does not show

Tags: c, opengl

I am loading bitmap file and creating texture this way:

```
LoadBitmapFromFile( "img.bmp", &bitmapFile );

glGenTextures(1, &texture[0] );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );


glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, bitmapFile.width, bitmapFile.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapFile.data);


glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                 GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );
```

Later on, I try to texture triangles:

```
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glPushMatrix();
            glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );
            glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP );
                glTexCoord2f( 0, 0 ); glVertex2f( 0, 768 );
                glTexCoord2f( 1, 0 ); glVertex2f( 1024, 768 );
                glTexCoord2f( 1, 1 ); glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
                glTexCoord2f( 0, 1 ); glVertex2f( 1024, 0 );
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

But texture doesn't show on screen, other coloured primitives do.

It does work with glDrawPixel, but doesn't texture triangles, what could be wrong?

I have simplified my app just to show the problem:
(also had to include glext, as it didn't found GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "glext.h"

typedef struct BitmapFile
{
    int width, height;
    unsigned char* data;
};

BitmapFile bitmapFile;

GLuint texture[1];

void LoadBitmapFromFile( char *filename, BitmapFile *bitmap )
{
    int bitmapSize = 0;
    int i = 0;

    FILE *file;

    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );
    if( !file )
    {
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&bitmap->width, 4, 1, file);

    fseek(file, 22, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&bitmap->height, 4, 1, file);

    fseek(file, 34, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&bitmapSize, 4, 1, file);

    bitmap->data = (unsigned char*)malloc(bitmapSize);
    fseek(file, 54, SEEK_SET);
    fread(bitmap->data, bitmapSize, 1, file);

    for( i = 0; i < bitmapSize; i+=3 )
    {
        int tempByte = bitmap->data[i];
        bitmap->data[i] = bitmap->data[i+2];
        bitmap->data[i+2] = tempByte;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int LoadGLTextures()                                  
{
    LoadBitmapFromFile( "img.bmp", &bitmapFile );

    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0] );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );


    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, bitmapFile.width, bitmapFile.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapFile.data);


    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );

    /*glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                     GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );

    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );*/
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);


    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE ); 
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );

    LoadGLTextures();

    glfwOpenWindowHint( GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE );
    glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0, 0, 255, 0, 32, 0, GLFW_WINDOW );


    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0.0, 1024, 768, 0, -1.0, 1.0); 
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );

    while( !glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) )
    {
        glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );
        glPushMatrix();

            glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP );
                glTexCoord2f( 0, 0 ); glVertex2f( 0, 768 );
                glTexCoord2f( 1, 0 ); glVertex2f( 1024, 768 );
                glTexCoord2f( 1, 1 ); glVertex2f( 0, 0 );
                glTexCoord2f( 0, 1 ); glVertex2f( 1024, 0 );
            glEnd();
        glPopMatrix();

        glDrawPixels( bitmapFile.width, bitmapFile.height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapFile.data);

        glfwSwapBuffers();
        glFlush();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/254/89567090.jpg/

---

Ok, I'm powerless, after last changes loading function looks like that:

```
int LoadGLTextures()                                  
{
    LoadBitmapFromFile( "img.bmp", &bitmapFile );

    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0] );
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0] );

    //glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, bitmapFile.width, bitmapFile.height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapFile.data);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, i+1, GL_RGB, bitmapFile.width/(2*(i+1)), bitmapFile.height/(2*(i+1)), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapFile.data);
    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    return true;
}
```

But on screen there are still no changes.
( bitmap is 256x256 )

Comment: you did not set you `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix. Try adding `glLoadIdentity():` after `glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading only one level but enable mipmaping by calling

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

If loading only one level you must *disable* mipmaping with

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

or

```
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

#### Update due to having seen the code:

The OP tried to load textures before a OpenGL context was available.

Comment: or by calling `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` if he actually wants mipmaps and doesn't want to generate them himself. edit: it seems to have a gotcha though: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Automatic_mipmap_generation

Comment: Nothing changes with any of them and for some reason it can't find glGenerateMipmap function

Comment: @Neomex: glGenerateMipmap is a function of recent OpenGL versions. However on Windows only functions of OpenGL-1.1 are directly accessible. For anything beyond you must load the further functions through the extension mechanism. The most easy way to do this is using the GL Extension Wrangler library (GLEW, http://glew.sf.net) – now if you happens to get a OpenGL context below OpenGL-2 – e.g. if you don't have the drivers from the GPU maker installed, but the Windows built in ones – then texture dimensions must be powers of 2 (1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, …). Width and height may differ though.

Comment: My bmp file is 256x256, I've get GLEW, but now when calling glGenerateMipmap it throws unhandled exception.

Comment: @Neomex: Did you  call glewInit() after creating the OpenGL context?

Comment: Before, more precisely, I've called glfw first, then glew, then rest of the program.

Comment: glfwInit() must be called after creating the context, that's important. So in case of GLFW after the call to glfwOpenWindow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6555/discussion-between-neomex-and-datenwolf)

Answer (score 1):

Are you drawing the triangles counterclockwise when viewed from your camera position? To test if that is the problem, call `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);`.

You should also always set the active texture unit before binding, try `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` before binding.

Comment: Disabling it doesn't change anything and it doesn't find glActiveTexture function

Comment: @Neomex well then this is not the problem, you could use `glActiveTextureARB(GL_TEXTURE0_ARB)` but `TEXTURE0` is the default anyways, so if you didn't touch it, it should be fine. On an unrelated note, that `glFlush()` is not necessary that's what the swapbuffers is there for.

Answer (score 1):

the problem looks similar to my previous response here:

[Android OpenGL2.0 showing black textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688980/android-opengl2-0-showing-black-textures/8748323#8748323)

This is a quite common issue of texturing on OpenGL.

In case of no-power of 2 textures, the wrap mode can only be GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE on most of the drivers implementations.

There are restrictions as well on the filter you can use which can be only GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR (in other words no MIPMAPPING)

2 Options here:

1. Try to change the texture size to power of 2
2. Change the clamping options from:

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

to

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

Cheers

Comment: The thing is, that my texture is power of two. ( using these commands doesn't change anything ). I had similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769389/error-while-loading-texture-with-soil but i though it is something wrong with library, so I've just written own bmp loading function.

Comment: How big is the texture? I had a similar problem due to texture size. If you are on mobile devices then it is quite often.

Answer (score 1):

YOu "forgot" to generate mipmaps.

Either disable mipmapping using methods suggested by datenwolf:

---

> glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

or

> glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);as

---

OR generate mipmaps.

To generate mipmaps:

1. In OpenGL 3 and higher use `glGenerateMipmap`.
2. In OpenGL 1.4 and higher use `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE)` for your texture.
3. In lower versions of OpenGL either use `gluBuild2DMipmaps` or generate them manually yourself for every texture level useing `glTexImage2D`.

Keep in mind that disabling mipmaps may negatively impact performance.

To *easily* access all of those functions on windows platform, you'll need something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Neomex: Yes, you're filing mipmaps with garbage data. Each mip-map level should contain downscaled version of previous level. Also, unless you're actually using pre-OpenGL 1.4 hardware (which is very unlikely this days) you should definitely use #1 or #2 instead of #3. Plus make sure triangle is visible if there is no texture. Also, the easiest way to troubleshoot the problem is to insert error checking (for GL errors) after every statement. You should try it.