# Open GL ES png texture rendering as black

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am just trying to draw a full screen `.png` into openGL as a texture. However, I am met with a black screen. My code works fine with jpegs, so I can only assume it's an issue with transparency.

Here is an example png, which it isn't working for: http://cl.ly/e5x4 (although it is opaque, it still doesn't render) (and no, it needs to be a .png)

Here is my code:

**glView.m**

```
struct vertex {
    float position[3];
    float color[4];
    float texCoord[2];
};

typedef struct vertex vertex;

const vertex vertices[] = {
    {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 167.0/255.0, 253.0/255.0, 1}, {1, 0}}, // BR (0)
    {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 222.0/255.0, 1.0, 1}, {1, 1}}, // TR (1)
    {{-1, 1, 0}, {0, 222.0/255.0, 1.0, 1}, {0, 1}}, // TL (2)
    {{-1, -1, 0}, {0, 167.0/255.0, 253.0/255.0, 1}, {0, 0}}, // BL (3)
};

const GLubyte indicies[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 2
};

@implementation glView {
    EAGLContext* context;

    GLuint positionSlot, colorSlot, textureCoordSlot;

    GLuint texture, textureUniform;

    GLuint vertexBuffer, indexBuffer;

}

-(GLuint) compileShader:(NSString*)shaderName withType:(GLenum)shaderType {

    NSString* shaderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:shaderName ofType:@"glsl"];
    NSError* err;

    NSString* shaderString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:shaderPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

    NSAssert(shaderString, @"Failed to load shader string: %@", err.localizedDescription);

    GLuint shaderHandle = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const char* shaderStringUTF8 = [shaderString UTF8String];
    int shaderStringLength = (int)[shaderString length];
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, &shaderStringUTF8, &shaderStringLength);

    glCompileShader(shaderHandle);

    GLint compileSuccess;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderHandle, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileSuccess);

    if (compileSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages];
        NSLog(@"%@", messageString);
        @throw NSInternalInconsistencyException;
    }

    return shaderHandle;
}

-(void) complileShaders {

    GLuint vertexShader = [self compileShader:@"vertexShader" withType:GL_VERTEX_SHADER];
    GLuint fragmentShader = [self compileShader:@"fragmentShader" withType:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER];

    GLuint programHandle = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programHandle, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programHandle, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(programHandle);

    GLint linkSuccess;
    glGetProgramiv(programHandle, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkSuccess);
    if (linkSuccess == GL_FALSE) {
        GLchar messages[256];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programHandle, sizeof(messages), 0, &messages[0]);
        NSString* messageString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:messages];
        NSLog(@"%@", messageString);
        @throw NSInternalInconsistencyException;
    }

    glUseProgram(programHandle);
    positionSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "position");
    colorSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "sourceColor");
    textureCoordSlot = glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "texCoordIn");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorSlot);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordSlot);

    textureUniform = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "tex");

}

-(instancetype) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {

        self.layer.opaque = YES;

        // Setup context
        context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

        NSAssert(context, @"Failed to initialise context.");
        NSAssert([EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context], @"Failed to set the current context.");

        // Setup render buffer
        GLuint colorBuffer;
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);
        [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:self.layer];

        // Setup frame buffer
        GLuint frameBuffer;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, colorBuffer);

        // Setup vertex buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // Setup index buffer
        glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indicies), indicies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        [self complileShaders];

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);


        texture = [self loadTexture:@"justapng.png"];

        [self render];

    }
    return self;
}

-(GLuint) loadTexture:(NSString*)fileName {

    UIImage* textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    NSAssert1(textureImage, @"Unable to load texture %@.", fileName);

    return [self loadTextureFromImage:textureImage];
}

-(GLuint) loadTextureFromImage:(UIImage*)image {

    CGImageRef textureImage = image.CGImage;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    GLubyte* spriteData = (GLubyte*) malloc(width*height*4);


    CGColorSpaceRef cs = CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage);
    CGContextRef c = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, cs, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(cs);

    CGContextDrawImage(c, (CGRect){CGPointZero, {width, height}}, textureImage);
    CGContextRelease(c);

    GLuint glTex;
    glGenTextures(1, &glTex);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (int)width, (int)height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

    free(spriteData);

    return glTex;
}

-(void) render {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(textureUniform, 0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*3));
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (GLvoid*)(sizeof(float)*7));


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indicies)/sizeof(indicies[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);


    [context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}


@end
```

**vertexShader.glsl**

```
attribute vec4 position;

attribute vec4 sourceColor;
varying vec4 destinationColor;

attribute vec2 texCoordIn;
varying vec2 texCoordOut;


void main() {
    destinationColor = sourceColor;
    gl_Position = position;
    texCoordOut = texCoordIn;
}
```

**fragmentShader.glsl**

```
varying lowp vec4 destinationColor;

varying lowp vec2 texCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = destinationColor*texture2D(tex, texCoordOut);
}
```

Sorry for dumping all this code, but I am unsure where the problem is originating from. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the classic non-power-of-two issue (eg. see [Android OpenGL2.0 showing black textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688980/android-opengl2-0-showing-black-textures)). The texture you linked is 1005x335.

The OpenGL ES 2.0 specification only allows for NPOT textures to be 'complete' with `glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)`. Various extensions allow NPOT texturing, however, your device doesn't necessarily support these, and likely doesn't if you're getting black textures. If a texture isn't complete, it is sampled as black per the spec.